# Woocommerce - can I sum quantity of specific products ordered by each user?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I came across these: [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details/44708344#44708344)

and was wondering if these commands are powerful enough to work like mysql commands where you can SUM(quantity) of a product purchased and then group that by userid ... ?

so say I had this table in my database of orders;

```
user | product | quantity
1 | chair | 4
2 | chair | 4
1 | chair | 6
2 | bench | 3
2 | bench | 2
```

would I be able to use those commands presented in the link above to get this?

```
user | product | quantity
1 | chair | 10
2 | chair | 4
2 | bench | 5
```

and if so ... how?? I wanna collate all the data in my orders by total quantity per product purchased per user in a php based table...

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

For your example it seems that **using a SQL query** is still **the most effective way**, even if you could use a the [`WC_Order_Query`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query). Developers still use a lot SQL queries when it's necessary, lighter and more accurate. The [WPDB Wordpress Class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) is the way to make that.

Additionally, there is a lot of Woocommerce specific built in functions that can be used too *(and some from Wordpress too)*.

All new [Woocommerce CRUD setters and getter methods](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/CRUD-Objects-in-3.0) are very powerful but used for example to get specific data from an order or to make changes programmatically in an existing Order, re-calculate totals and save it to the database.

For CRUD methods around the order object, you can take a look to the source code in [`WC_Checkout` for the `create_order()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#255-345) method that will show you that those methods are used to create a complete order. As you will see at the end, [the method `save()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html#_save) will register all the data in the database.

**To resume:** There is no an unique way, but many, depending on what you want to do, on the time to be spent and on your skills. **For you the way here is a SQL query.**

> For the **"how to do it?"** You already asked that [in your other related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50774214/generate-a-table-of-orders-grouped-by-user-id-which-sums-quantity-of-product) and **Gordon Linoff** *(a top rated user for SQL and mySQL)* can really help you with that complex SQL query.

Comment: Thank you for your response! it looks like a SQL query is my best option... Just gotta figure out how to format the query. Still trying to to grasp SQL queries from multiple tables!